# How do I match with Regex with word boundaries?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using JavaScript:

`::add ::stuff more::word`

I want to match `::add` and `::stuff`, but not `::word`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [non-word boundary **`\B`**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#notb) here:

```
var r = '::add ::stuff more::word'.match(/\B::\w+/g);
console.log(r); //=> [ '::add', '::stuff' ]
```